identifying component 12QF 65I COVQ
Can you please help identifying this component with top marking:
12QF
65I
COVQ
Device: an earlier 2020 revision of Xmos isolated I2S USB interface



Can you please add a second picture showing the surrounding context of this IC and mention the kind of device, that contains this PCB?

Thanks for the feedback. Edit done.

It's a Texas Instruments LP5912Q3.3DRVTQ1 LDO regulator.


(Source: lcsc.com)
